# Austro-Hungarian or Austrian-Hungarian?

Tags: demonyms

While reading on the [Austro-Hungarian rule in Bosnia and Herzegovina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austro-Hungarian_rule_in_Bosnia_and_Herzegovina) in Wikipedia:

> Their goals, however, were no obstacle to economic cooperation with the **Austrian-Hungarian** authorities [...]
>   This was done as the **Austrian-Hungarian** authorities had a plan to isolate Bosnia and Herzegovina from its neighbouring Slavic countries, Croatia and Serbia, and to halt the national aspirations of the peoples in Bosnia and Herzegovina.

The demonym choice for Austria-Hungary piqued my curiosity. Is it correct to say *Austrian-Hungarian* or would *Austro-Hungarian* be more appropiate?

Comment: In this context, "Austrian-Hungarian" stands for "Austrian and Hungarian", when "Austro-Hungarian" would refer to the former [Austria-Hungary empire 1867-1918](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austria-Hungary).

Comment: @Graffito I think it has something to do with avoiding ambiguity like using African-American instead of Afro-American. What do you think?

Comment: @Graffito Doubtful, although I could be convinced by evidence.  *Austrian-Hungarian authorities* means the officials of the governmental bodies granted authority by the union of kingdoms known in English as the Austrian-Hungarian Empire (1867-1918).

Comment: @vickyace - For me (and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_Americans)) African American and Afro-Americans are synonyms. Back to Europe, there is presently no real issue related to Austrian minorities in Hungary (respectively to Hungarian minority in Austria) justifying a disambiguation.

Comment: @vickyace What ambiguity?  Black US citizens adopted *African-American*, likely by analogy.  US citizens of Italian descent call themselves Italian-Americans, not Italo-Americans.  *Afro-American* has at least 150 years in the language and graced the name of a Harvard University academic department in the 1990s.

Comment: @deadrat - At first glance, I thought that the text was refering to the [Yugoslav Wars 1991-2001](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yugoslav_Wars), but following your comment, I realized that [Bosnian crisis / 1908-1909](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bosnian_crisis) occured during the reign of Franz Joseph that was the Austro-Hungarian Emperor. Then, Austrian-Hungarian might be a synonym of Austro-Hungarian.

Comment: @Graffito Yeah, that Balkan nonsense has been going on for centuries. It can be hard to tell the difference between eras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

English usage prefers *Austro-Hungarian* (Empire).  I suspect 'Austrian-Hungarian' is a direct transposition from the German *Österreichisch-Ungarische* (Monarchie) by someone unfamiliar with the English usage.